# Is BPP= P known for ANY uniform model of computation?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, derandomization

Many believe that **BPP** $=$ **P** "should" hold for Turing machines. We even have some "witnesses" for this: otherwise some "strange" things would happen; see e.g. this [paper](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IW97/proc.pdf) by Implagliazzo and Wigderson.
But the proof of **BPP** $=$ **P** remains still 
not in sight. The main difficulty seems here to lie  in the *uniformity*:
we have *one* randomized algorithm working for inputs of *every* dimension (length) $n$, and we want to also find  *one* deterministic algorithm working for inputs of *every* dimension $n$.

It is long known, at least since [Adleman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly), that **BPP** $\subseteq$ **P**/poly holds in the *non-uniform* setting (even for algorithms computing functions over *infinite* domains, like  arithmetic circuits working over all real numbers). The disadvantage of these results is, however, that after the derandomizing, we get a *sequence* of deterministic algorithms, that can be *different* for inputs from *different* dimensions $n$.

But if we are unable to show **BPP** $=$ **P** in the model of Turing machines, can we at least show this in some **restricted** uniform, but still "practically relevant" models of computation?
One of such models is that of  *dynamic programming* algorithms. At a high (extremely high) level, the model of DP algorithms can be described as follows. We parameterize a given problem $P$ by one (or more) parameters $n$ ("dimension" of inputs), consider the resulting "subproblems" $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ and give one (or more) recurrence equations

$P_n(x)$ = minimum or maximum of some arithmetic combination of the subproblems $P_m(x)$ for $m < n $.

In a *randomized* DP algorithm, we allow some additional *random variables* be used as parameters in the recursion equations. Even if very vaguely defined, this model is uniform: we have *one* DP recurrence for *all* dimension $n$. But the model is "clearly" much weaker than the (universal) model of Turing machines: no loops, no "crazy" operations - just min or max combined with arithmetic operations.

> **Question:** Is **BPP** = **P** known for (at least restricted) DP algorithms?

What, say, about DP algorithms that only use $\min,+$ or $\max,+$ operations in their recursion equations? 
Actually, I am not aware of *any* proof of **BPP** = **P** in any "non-pathological", at least "somewhat interesting"  but *uniform* model of computation (whatever these "non-pathological" and  "somewhat interesting" should mean).

**N.B.** I have no "stomach feeling" concerning the issue of *uniformity* in computation. So, any hints/references even to "well-known" results, are welcome.

**Note** [added 27.11.2017] My question actually is: can we capture THE barrier for derandomization in the *uniform* setting? After Adleman's theorem, one serious "barrier" for extending it to circuit (or decision trees) working over *infinite* domains $D$ (like $\mathbb{R}^n$, instead of $\{0,1\}^n$) seemed to lie in the *infinity* of the domain. Adleman's theorem simulates probabilistic circuits by majority vote of about $\log|D|$ deterministic circuits (Chernoff bounds then suffice). But this (infiniteness of $D$) turned out to be *no* barrier: it is then enough to replace $\log|D|$ by the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension of deterministic circuits.

To be a bit more precise, let ${\cal C}$ be some class of circuit of size at most $t=t(n)$ computing functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$.
Under a  *probabilistic circuit of size $t$* I'll mean just a probability distribution $\mathrm{Pr}:{\cal C}\to[0,1]$. Such a "circuit" *computes* a given function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ if $\mathrm{Pr}\{C\in{\cal C}\colon C(x)=f(x)\}\geq 2/3$ holds for every (single) input $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The *VC dimension* of ${\cal C}$ is the largest natural number $v$ (if there is one) for which there exist $v$ circuits $C_1,\ldots,C_v$ in ${\cal C}$ with the following property:

- for every $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,v\}$ there is a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}$ such that
      $C_i(x)=y$ iff $i\in S$.

The ["uniform convergence in probability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence_in_probability) results from statistical learning theory yield the tool for derandomization.

> **Infinite Majority Rule:** If a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ can be computed by a probabilistic circuit of size $t(n)$, then $f$ can be computed as a majority vote of $m=O(v)$ deterministic circuits of size $t(n)$, where $v=v(n)$ is the VC dimension of deterministic circuits of size at most $t(n)$.

This rule holds also in the *uniform* setting: I admittedly used "$t(n)"$ for the size of circuits - this could well be the running *time* of Turing machines. The reason why this does not show the **BPP** = **P** 
 lies in the **inherent non-uniformity** of what this rule delivers: when the dimension $n$ **grows**, we are forced to compute majority votes of **growing** sets of Turing machines.

But this only kills of the VC approach towards resolving the **BPP** vs. **P** problem. My hope therefore is that people have tried some "next to pathological" **restricted** but **uniform** models to detect THE barrier for derandomization in the *uniform* setting.
I am aware of the connection of **BPP** vs. **P** problem with the existence of pseudo-random generators, and similar. But all these results are trying to find the "barrier" in the **most general** setting, when **all** Turing machines are in our disposal. What, however, if we "bind hands" of machines - can perhaps then this "uniformity monster" disclose its power? Being unable to derandomize  *general* models of computation, it seems natural to try to detect the uniformity-barrier in **restricted** models.